# Does there exist a direct way of proving Cauchy's integral formula?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

**Cauchy's integral formula**  $:$

> If $D$ be a simply connected domain and $\gamma$ is a closed contour in $D$, then for any analytic function $f$ in $D$ and $a \in D \setminus \{\gamma \}$, $$f(a)n(\gamma ; a) = \frac {1} {2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac {f(\zeta)} {\zeta - a}\ d{\zeta}.$$

Now my question is "Does there any process which directly proves the above formula?" i.e. a process which does not involve Cauchy-Goursat theorem, Cauchy's theorem for disk etc. Actually if it exists then that would be time preserving in exams, I guess. Otherwise we have to deal with lots of lemmas or results which actually wastes lots of time and exhausts us in exams. So I and some of my friends are feared off thinking that how could we manage time in exam hall if these kind of laborious questions happen to be in the question paper. Please give me some suggestions about overcoming such problems.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider the case $f(z) = (z-a) g(z)$ where $g(z)$ is analytic.

Comment: Do you mean $g$ is analytic for $z \neq a$?

Answer (score 1):

For analytic functions the Cauchy integral theorem is not hard to prove : start with $f$ given by a power series on a disk

> $f(z) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (z-a)^n $ for $|z-a| < r$ so that $F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_n}{n+1} (z-a)^{n+1}$ is an (analytic) primitive. Therefore $\int_\gamma f(z)dz = F(\gamma(1))-F(\gamma(0))$

then extend to finite ($\scriptstyle \text{and simply connected}$) union of such disks, splitting $\gamma$ into parts contained in each disk.

Finally if $f$ is analytic then $$\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-s}dz = \int_\gamma \frac{f(s)}{z-s}dz+\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)-f(s)}{z-s}dz$$ where $\frac{f(z)-f(s)}{z-s}$ is analytic and $\int_\gamma \frac{f(s)}{z-s}dz = f(s)\, 2i\pi \, \eta(\gamma,s)$

---

To make it more clear : by definition, analytic functions have locally a primitive. And those assemble to a global primitive on **simply connected** open sets. Once this is achieved, the Cauchy integral theorem and formula become trivial.

Comment: But within each such disk there is only a segmentation of $\gamma$ which is *not* closed.

Comment: @Vim The main point is the existence of a primitive. Also you can make small parts of $\gamma$ closed if you'd like.

Comment: Can you elaborate? It seems tricky to me how to relate the integral with the winding numbers.

Comment: @Vim $\int_\gamma \frac{f(s)}{z-s}dz = f(s)\, 2i\pi \, \eta(\gamma,s)$. There is nothing tricky here, I swear

Comment: Yes you're right. Sorry I kind of misread your answer. Now as I understand, the key point is that $\frac{f(z)-f(s)}{z-s}$ has a removable singularity at $s$ so is analytic and thus its integral on the closed curve $\gamma$ vanishes. However, I think it is still non-trivial why analytic functions must admit primitives, without building on Goursat's Theorem etc.

Comment: @Vim ? analytic functions have locally a primitive, this is by definition, and those assemble globally (on simply connected open sets, of course) by definition of primitives as $C+\int_a^z f(s)ds$

Comment: i don't know how the existence of local primitives follows directly by definition. In Stein's complex analysis, this builds on Goursat. (To be specific, Stein uses the horizontal-vertical path integral as local primtives, but to prove they are indeed the primitive, one cannot avoid having to prove path integrals on a triangular path vanish.)

Comment: @Vim See the yellow part of my answer ! No, Stein proves it for holomorphic functions, which are not known to be analytic (before the Cauchy integral formula for holomorphic functions).

Comment: @reuns would you please explain how does the extension over finite number open disk work? I don't understand it clearly.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee  $\int_a^b f(z)dz = F(b)-F(a)$ stays true for finite (simply connected) union of disks